# Rectangle overlap with PDFPTable

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm creating a program that generates a PDF file using Java and iText.

I added a Rectangle using PDFContentByte and Table with PDFPTable.

The first thing I created was the table and it works fine but when I added the Rectangle, I found it overlapping with the table I just created a while ago. I don't know how to solve this problem. I want to look it simply like this:

```
====================================

________________________________
|          RECTANGLE           |
|______________________________|
________________________________
|____________TABLE_____________|
|________|___________|_________|
|________|___________|_________|
|________|___________|_________|

====================================
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing direct content (added at coordinates you've defined) with content that follows the layout defined by iText (because you're using `document.add()`). You should stick to either defining your own layout, or letting iText do the layout.

(1:) Defining your own layout means: don't add the table using `document.add(table);` use `table.writeSelectedRows()` instead. There's a danger to this approach: if the table exceeds the size of the page, it will 'drop off the page'. Why? Because you've taken control over the layout. You need to make sure you're adding all the content at the correct positions.

(2:) Letting iText do the layout means: instead of adding a `Rectangle` with `PdfContentByte`, add a `PdfTable` with one column and one row. Define a fixed height for the single `PdfPCell` and use border, border color and background color of the cell to define the border and the color of the rectangle. Add the special table (that looks like a `Rectangle`) first, then add the real table. Maybe you want to define some 'spacing-before' or 'spacing-after' for the tables.